# Posting entry to wufoo with js/jquery

Tags: wufoo

I'm trying to post a new to entry to an existing Wufoo form using only js/jquery.
The docs are not very clear on this, they all use php for posting.
As I believe it is possible I was wondering if someone could post a sample of the post url and formatting of the params.

Edit: I am aware of the jquery wufoo wrapper, but it seems very old and not relevant anymore.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Spoken with Wufoo guys, there is no way to do it with Ajax (cross domain issues) and they are not planning on fixing it anytime soon.